# How to get current date in MDX date range clause?

Tags: sql-server, mdx

I have a MDX query that is pulling data from the cube. I require to add a date range condition so it is pulling data from 2019 onwards to the current date.

I have never worked with MDX before therefore used report builder.

This is the query I have, but instead of null I want it to be upto current date:

```
SELECT 
    NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Premium LCL] } ON COLUMNS, 
    NON EMPTY { (
            [D_BU].[Business Unit Number].[Business Unit Number].ALLMEMBERS * 
            [D_TransactionDate].[Accounting Year].[Accounting Year].ALLMEMBERS *
            [D_TransactionDate].[Accounting Month Year].[Accounting Month Year].ALLMEMBERS * 
            [D_BU].[Region Name].[Region Name].ALLMEMBERS * 
            [D_BU].[Branch Name].[Branch Name].ALLMEMBERS *  
            [D_Industry_SIC].[SIC Level 3 Name].[SIC Level 3 Name].ALLMEMBERS 
            ) } DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION ON ROWS 
FROM 
    ( 
     SELECT 
        ( 
         { [D_BU].[RegionName].&[UK - Underwriting]  
                   [D_BU].[RegionName].&[UK] } 
            ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM 
       ( 
    SELECT 
        ( 
        -{ [D_BU].[BranchName].&[Re Centre],
           [D_BU].[BranchName].&[UK&Ireland] } 
        ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM 
      ( 
    SELECT 
        ( 
           [D_TransactionDate].[Accounting Year].&[2019] : null 
        ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM 
    [Model]
))) 
WHERE ( [D_BU].[RegionName].CurrentMember ) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE
```